# How to detect if an Internet Explorer plugin is already installed using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox-addon

For Firefox, it is possible to detect if a Firefox extension is installed using JavaScript by checking whether a specific image is existing on chrome://. But, how can i do the detection on Internet Explorer for an Internet Explorer plugin using JavaScript or others.

Thanks.

Comment: The "load chrome:// images from web" bug has been fixed almost 4 years ago... In the general case - you cannot detect whether a specific Firefox extension is installed and that's good. [For reference](http://adblockplus.org/blog/web-pages-accessing-chrome-is-forbidden)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure wich plugin you want to detect, but this might help you

http://www.builtfromsource.com/2007/06/26/detecting-plugins-in-internet-explorer-and-a-few-hints-for-all-the-others/

EDIT: Original link is 404

http://www.matthewratzloff.com/blog/2007/06/26/detecting-plugins-in-internet-explorer-and-a-few-hints-for-all-the-others/

EDIT: Internet Archive to the rescue

https://web.archive.org/web/20170806025526/http://www.matthewratzloff.com/blog/2007/06/26/detecting-plugins-in-internet-explorer-and-a-few-hints-for-all-the-others/