# Browser extensions cause errors on website

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, internet-explorer-9

Extensions installed on Chrome and IE sometimes cause errors on my website. I want that extensions do not affect my website, can I block them with JavaScript? And I know it sounds a little bit stupid :) Anyway any suggestions are welcome

Comment: Is a specific extension? What is the name of the extension?

Comment: @marcelo2605 Several extensions caused error, I have deleted them and don't know there names any more :(

Comment: a sad news:had there been a way,today adblock extensions would not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot block extensions using javascript but you may check if the user has a certain extension installed and displaying a warning or error regarding the extension like "uploads won't work when XY is enabled"

How to do this has already been discussed on SO

[Check whether user has a Chrome extension installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293498/check-whether-user-has-a-chrome-extension-installed)

[How to detect if an Internet Explorer plugin is already installed using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818736/how-to-detect-if-an-internet-explorer-plugin-is-already-installed-using-javascri)

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't any way to block extensions from a webpage.